# Recommend Bug Tracking software for Beta app

Tags: php, mysql, bug-tracking

I need a PHP/MySQL based Bug Tracking script that will allow me to put up a downloads section and focus each download to have it's own issue list.

I can't seem to find any Bug tracking scripts that can do this.

Can anyone recommend me one, I prefer opensource, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll get lucky with a bug tracker supporting a *file* oriented bug list as such. However, most bug tracking systems allow you to file bugs related to a specific *version* or release number.

Giving each download a version/build/release number, and filing bugs against that number, is the way to go.

As to software recommendations, there are several questions dealing with that already:

- [Lightweight, minimalist PHP bug/feature request tracking system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111772/lightweight-minimalist-php-bug-feature-request-tracking-system) (PHP oriented)
- [What bug tracking software do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328/what-bug-tracking-software-do-you-use) (All languages/platforms)

A bug tracker that supports filing bugs against a version number and a flexible structure of projects and sub-projects is [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org). It's my personal bug tracking recommendation next to [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org). They're both not PHP based, though.

Comment: Also many bug trackers support projects.  If you are supporting different products, you can setup a project for each product and then have your download page link directly to the project for each one.

Comment: Thanks guys , well it's mainly one project and different version numbers, I know a bug tracker can easily support this, but I would like an area for the user to download the files as well, located mainly in the versions information area.

Comment: @Sandeep then check out Redmine, IIRC it does what you want